# Where to integrate getStream.io

Tags: android, getstream-io

I am a noob in backend programming. I have been looking into getstream activity feed api for a while and I am still not clear where to integrate the api. Consider that I have built an Instagram like application using native android (say JAVA) and the backend is PHP or PYTHON. Is getStream api still helpful for me? If so should I be integrating in into frontend or backend?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately right now there is no Android SDK for `Feeds`. The development is planned, although there is still no exact date when it will be ready.

There is `iOS` SDK for `Feeds`: https://getstream.io/ios-activity-feed/tutorial/

And `ReactNative`: https://getstream.io/react-native-activity-feed/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So for now we can only use this api for the backend. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: No, there are backend, iOS, react native and react SDKs. But there is no Android one. So you can start building you app (service). Later when Android SDK is released you can add native Android app as well.